# Help me please to identify this Chinese plant/dish?

Tags: food

Can you kindly help me translate and/or identify english name for this plant/dish

http://www.foodreport.cn/nutrition.php?action=view&id=228
http://www.nipic.com/show/1/55/5740675k344c9c09.html

Comment: Try 凉拌贡菜 in baidu.com you will get lots of pretty pics! I don't think it has to be asparagus, any old veggies will do!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I don't feel "what is this thing?" is meaningfully about the Chinese language.

Answer (score 3):

It's difficult to translate names of Chinese dishes into English, because of the huge differences between Chinese and Western cuisine.

The dish featured on the page is called:

**凉拌贡菜** (liangban gongcai), 
character by character:

- 凉 cold
- 拌 to toss (salad)
- 贡 to tribute
- 菜 dish

So it's basically a salad that is served cold.

The main ingredient is known as **贡菜** (gong cai) in Chinese, which is sometimes also written as 'gong choi' or 'yamakurage' (Japanese name).

If I am wrong, do correct me.

EDIT: There are some nice photos out there on the [dish](https://www.flickr.com/photos/fotoosvanrobin/6662196739/) (gongcai salad) and on the [cultivation of gongcai](http://flickrhivemind.net/Tags/gongcai,magnoliopsida/Interesting), as well.

Comment: @Sasha I must warn you, that you should double check if yamakurage really is the thing in the image and as for the 'Chinese asparagus', I am not sure about that. Wait for other users to contribute to this, see if they have more details.