# What's this vegetable in Taiwan called?

Tags: vocabulary, food

Please tell me what this vegetable in Taiwan is called in Chinese. (I also don't know its English name so can't look it up in a dictionary.)

[image: mystery vegetable in Taipei]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about food identification. Try http://cooking.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: @congusbongus: It is about food identification **and** Chinese vocabulary. Cooking.SE is about cooking and I have no question about cooking this mystery vegetable. Therefore it would be more off topic there. Even if they accepted the question they are unlikely to also know the Chinese word.

Comment: [Precedent.](http://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/10808) Zero votes but has an answer and has not been closed, even though it's asking for the English word rather than the Chinese word.

Comment: We name it ladies finger. (Malaysia, Singapore)

Comment: In English, it's called [okra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Okra), ochro, or ladies' fingers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called 秋葵 in Mainland China. So is it in Taiwan I guess.

Comment: I thought is 羊角豆

Comment: 羊角豆 is another name of 秋葵.

Comment: okra in English.